# Attach image capture to send email

Tags: android, email

I tested this code in a mobile Xperia Mini and it worked successfully but now I tested in another mobile and it doesn't work, all right.... the name of the file attached is ok, but it doesn't appears the bytes in the the program to send email (gmail)

The file exists on the sdcard but  i don't know the reason by which it doesn't attached...

```
    String a=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "myfile.jpg";

Intent emailIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAdresses);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectText);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+ a));

emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); // I changed that to image but nothing

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Check your app:"),EMAIL_REQUEST);
```

The file is saved on this way  :

String  a=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "myfile.jpg";

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(a));         
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);

startActivityForResult(i,CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Any idea ? Thanks for all...

Comment: Why don't you use Uri.fromFile() also when you put the android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM extra? Anyway from you code you are missing one /, should be file://

Comment: Thanks but I have just tested Uri.fromFile and file:// and it doesn't work, the same problem all ok but the attached file is empty and really it's in the sdcard because I can see it ! ...I don't understand ! Maybe permissions ?